# Is there an algorithm that divide a square cell grid map into 3 or 4 equal spaces?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

So for example I have divide my map into something like this:
[click on link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpWjL.png)

the matrix representative would be

0 1 0 1 0

1 1 1 1 0

0 1 1 1 1

0 1 0 0 0

one of the way I could divide it into even-ish would be: 
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63bMp.png)

where total square is 11 and since 11/3 gives us a decimal, I need to have 2 space with 4 square and one space with 3 squares.

but I don't know an algorithm that will be able to divide a small map like that.

there is probably a code that will be able to solve that particular map, but what if it is like :

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
```

Each value is a square in the map and 1 is the square that should be considered.  0 is an empty/null space that is not part of the map and should not be taken into consideration when dividing the map.

So far I try a for loop adding all value and divide by 3 to determine how many squares is needed for each space. Also, if I get a decimal, then one space can have one more square than the other. So in this problem there is 36 squares so if I try to divide it into 3 space, then each space would have 12 squares.

So I am looking to see if there is an algorithm that will be able to solve all types of map.

Comment: What is the question? What did you try?

Comment: @John Sorry for being pedantic, but a question is something with a question mark. A summarizing sentence with a question mark would help to understand what exactly your question is. Simple as that.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how you get 37 for that example. The grid is 4 x 10, and there are four 0's. Last time I checked, 40 - 4 = 36.

Comment: It's also not at all clear what question you're asking. Exactly how do you want to divide the map? Do you want adjacent squares to be together in the split? Or can you just throw any 12 values into a map square? Without a better description of the expected output, there's no way we can give you meaningful suggestions.

Comment: @JimMischel  I added pictures

Comment: @Gassa I fixed the question

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have updated it

Answer (score 1):

This is actually NP-hard for k>=2, where you want k=3 or k=4:

[theorem 2.2 in **On the complexity of partitioning graphs into connected subgraphs** - *M.E. DYER, A.M. FRIEZE*](http://math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Texfiles/COMPLEXPART.pdf)

You can get a decent answer by greedily removing nodes from your graph, and backtracking if you can't merge the remaining nodes.

It would help if you gave a more rigorous definition of 'even-ish' - for example, consider a map with 13 nodes - Would you rather have divisions of size (4,4,5), (3,3,3,4), (4,4,4,1), (5,5,3), or (4,4,3,2)?

Comment: My definition of even-ish is (4,4,5) if asked to divide into 3 and (3,3,3,4) if ask to divide in 4